# PIL linux(qnap)

Tags: python, pil, pillow, linux

Добрый день. Мне потребовалось, чтобы потон рисовал картинки в определённых местах. Для этого был выбран модуль PIL и pillow.
qnap порезали систему linux поэтому мне пришлось побороться с ней, чтобы установил pil (ушла неделя т.к. Я о linux не чего не знаю). После установки Я обрадовался, попробовал написать простейшую программу, которая рисует круг красного цвета и без вопросов записывает его в файл

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw   
image = Image.new("RGBA", (320,320), (0,0,0,0))    
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) 
draw.ellipse((10,10,300,300), fill="red", outline="red")   
del draw   
image.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

на виндовс такой же текст работает без проблем но здесь выдал ошибку

```
$ python pil2.py  

Traceback (most recent call last):     File "pil2.py", line 6, in <module>   

  image.save("test.png", "PNG")                                                                                                                                                                File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 1685, in save                    

  def __init__(self, im, box):                                                                                                                                                                     
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 706, in _save                    


  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 473, in _save                    

  # FIXME: make MAXBLOCK a configuration parameter 
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 432, in _getencoder              

  # -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
IOError: encoder zip not available
```

Подскажите в чём проблема. Я устал биться с этой системой проще уже взять ноут без монитора и установить в него чистый linux или подобную систему.
PS
для установки pil мне пришлось установить gcc и затем командами

```
$ python setup.py build

$ python setup.py install
```

устанавливать. Так же установил easy_install, pip
при установки писал

```
warning: no files found matching '*.yaml'  
warning: no files found matching '*.bdf' under directory 'Images'  
warning: no files found matching '*.fli' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'Images'  
warning: no files found matching '*.icns' under directory 'Images' 
warning: no files found matching '*.ico' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.pbm' under directory 'Images' 
warning: no files found matching '*.pil' under directory 'Images'    
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'Images'  
warning: no files found matching '*.ppm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.psd' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching '*.tar' under directory 'Images'  
warning: no files found matching '*.webp' under directory 'Images'  
warning: no files found matching '*.xpm' under directory 'Images'
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Sane'  
warning: no files found matching 'README' under directory 'Scripts'
warning: no files found matching '*.icm' under directory 'Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'Tk'
```

может из за этого?

Comment: Ну вам же ошибку указали: IOError: encoder zip not available, значит надо с нею разбираться.

[Первая строчка поиска](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/about-the-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available)

Либо, может быть, [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258335/ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available-ubuntu-python-pil) поможет

Answer (score 1):

1. пакет `python-pil` даже устанавливать не пришлось: уже стоит, возможно, с самой установки дистрибутива, или установился по какой-то зависимости.
2. запустил вашу программу:

   ```
   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
   image = Image.new("RGBA", (320,320), (0,0,0,0))
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
   draw.ellipse((10,10,300,300), fill="red", outline="red")
   del draw
   image.save("test.png", "PNG")
   ```
3. получил файл `test.png`:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]